# Need sql select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table structure in my database.

```
  Table User
      --------------
      UserID EmailAddress Password Gender DOB      Location
      ------------------------------------------------------
      1      bob@bob.com  bobbie   M      1/1/2009 New York City
      2      jon@jon.com  jonathan M      2/2/2008 Los Angeles
      3      joe@joe.com  joseph   M      1/2/2007 Pittsburgh


      Table Friends
      ---------------
      UserID FriendID
      ----------------
      1      2
      1      3
      2      3
```

This will show that `Bob is friends with both Jon and Joe` and that `Jon is also friends with Joe`.

In this example we will assume that friendship is always two ways, so you would not need a row in the table such as `(2,1) or (3,2)` because they are already represented in the other direction.

**And now I need query to retrieve jon's friend names.**

Comment: And what did you try? This is not a free code service after all...

Comment: select name from tab_users where userid in ((select frndid, userid from tab_frnd where userid = 2) OR
(select userid from tab_frnd where frndid =2) );

Comment: I have tried something like this.

Comment: @ Matteo Tassinari- I have tried it in my way.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UserName -- or any other field you want about the friend
FROM User
WHERE 
   UserID IN(
     SELECT FriendID
     FROM Friends
     WHERE
        UserID = 2) -- Assuming 2 is the UserID of Jon.
OR
    UserID IN(
       SELECT UserID
       FROM Friends
       WHERE 
         FriendID = 2) -- to include the other way around.
```

Comment: @RahulParit As I've described, look at the comment in the first line. I do not know what is the name of the field you're trying to select - edit it to fit your means. (i.e if your fieldname is Name, change "UserName" to "Name")

Comment: thank you so much.. i got it when after you edited it.

Comment: your first answer was not giving proper answer. but now it works fine.